# How to convert float64 time to datetime object

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime-format, python-xarray

I am working on Berkeley Earth Surface Temperature data. I have a monthly NetCDF file from 1753-recent. The date axis is float64 and when I convert to DateTime format it only returns the first day and month of each year. Below is the time documentation from Berkeley Earth Surface Temperature data:

> time: A list of times at which data is reported.  The data format is decimal
> with year and fraction of year reported, with each value corresponding
> to the midpoint of the respective month.  For example, 1981.125
> indicates February 1981.

I tried to convert DateTime from float to int and then apply pd.to_datetime().
It returns a value error when I use month in the format.

```
pd.to_datetime(dset.time.astype(int), format="%m%Y")
ValueError: time data '1850' does not match format '%m%Y' (match)


pd.to_datetime(dset.time.astype(int), format=%Y")
DatetimeIndex(['1850-01-01', '1850-01-01', '1850-01-01', '1850-01-01',
           '1850-01-01', '1850-01-01', '1850-01-01', '1850-01-01',
           '1850-01-01', '1850-01-01',
           ...
           '2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2022-01-01',
           '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01',
           '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=2071, freq=None)
```

I am new to xarray and NetCDF files, any help would be appreciated. Here is the link to the website - http://berkeleyearth.org/data/

Here is a description of my data:

```
 <xarray.Dataset>
 Dimensions:  (longitude: 360, latitude: 180, time: 2071, month_number: 12)
 Coordinates:
     * longitude    (longitude) float32 -179.5 -178.5 -177.5 ... 177.5 178.5 179.5
     * latitude     (latitude) float32 -89.5 -88.5 -87.5 -86.5 ... 87.5 88.5 89.5
     * time         (time) float64 1.85e+03 1.85e+03 ... 2.022e+03 2.023e+03
 Dimensions without coordinates: month_number
 Data variables:
     land_mask    (latitude, longitude) float64 ...
     temperature  (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
     climatology  (month_number, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
 Attributes:
 Conventions:           Berkeley Earth Internal Convention (based on CF-1.5)
     title:                 Native Format Berkeley Earth Surface 
     Temperature A...
     history:               27-Aug-2022 08:16:14
     institution:           Berkeley Earth Surface Temperature Project
     land_source_history:   05-Aug-2022 11:14:59
     ocean_source_history:  27-Aug-2022 05:20:43
     comment:               This file contains Berkeley Earth surface temperature...
```

I am guessing this is what you meant by top rows:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 2071)>
array([1850.041667, 1850.125   , 1850.208333, ..., 2022.375   , 2022.458333,
   2022.541667])
Coordinates:
    * time     (time) float64 1.85e+03 1.85e+03 1.85e+03 ... 2.022e+03 2.023e+03
Attributes:
units:          year A.D.
standard_name:  time
long_name:      Time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the floating point date to a format that can be converted by `pd.to_datetime`. Based on the description you have provided, you can extract (assuming `fdate` represents the floating point date value):

```py
year = int(fdate)
month = int((fdate - year) * 12) + 1
```

and then convert that to a string in the form `mmyyyy` using an `f-string`:

```py
f'{month:02d}{year:04d}'
```

That can then be converted to a datetime using format `%m%Y`. Wrapping it in a function:

```py
def convert_date(fdate):
    year = int(fdate)
    month = int((fdate - year) * 12) + 1
    return f'{month:02d}{year:04d}'
```

you would then use it as:

```py
pd.to_datetime(xr.apply_ufunc(convert_date, dset.time, vectorize=True), format='%m%Y')
```

Comment: There was an error. TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars. So I use astype() to convert it to int. But when I try to convert that to a string, it gave an error. TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.__format__

Comment: I've updated my post with a data description.

Comment: Can you include a couple of rows of `dset`?

Comment: I've updated my post. I'm new to xarray and still learning. So I guess this is what you meant by top rows.